# Compilation error: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

Tags: c, compilation, linker

While trying to compile a C program using make file, I am facing the following linking error described below.

I know this kind of issues are already discussed in many other posts, but I tried with solutions suggested in them but they all did not work.

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh

libclntsh.so and libclntsh.so.10.1 are  present in oracle path  /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib and that is being given as -L option in make file. Still I am facing the issue:-

```
Linking yieldrpt ...
cc -v -g -D_HPUX_SOURCE -DPARETO -Wl,-aarchive -L/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/         yieldrpt.o  -lclntsh `cat /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/ldflags`   -lmalloc -ldl -lm   \
                -lmalloc -o yieldrpt
Using built-in specs.
Target: i386-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=i386-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
/usr/libexec/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/collect2 --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 --hash-style=gnu -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o yieldrpt /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtbegin.o -L/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/ -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../.. -aarchive yieldrpt.o -lclntsh -lnbeq10 -lnhost10 -lnus10 -lnldap10 -lldapclnt10 -lnsslb10 -lntcp10 -lntcps10 -lnsslb10 -lntcp10 -lntns10 -lmalloc -ldl -lm -lmalloc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/crtend.o     /usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [yieldrpt] Error 1
```

Please let me know if any other info is needed.
Thank you

Comment: maybe a 32bit vs. 64bit issue?

Comment: Please `ls -alg  /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/*clntsh*`.

Comment: /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/clntsh.map /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.10.1 /u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/lib/libclntsh.so.10.1

Comment: @ ammoq: surprisingly lib and lib32 are pointing to the same folder in my oracle installation for 10.2. Would that really be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `-aarchive` to the linker. This is an HP/UX compatibility option
that is synonymous with `-Bstatic`, which directs the linker not to link dynamic
libraries. Hence your `libclntsh.so` is ignored. See [the documentation](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

If you don't know why this option is there you may well remove it and try again. If you
know it is necessary then you will have to find static libraries, including `libclntsh.a` to
link against.

Answer (score 0):

If you have libclntsh.so.12.1 or similar is already installed you may try symlinking the library to libclntsh.so with the following command: ln -s /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib/libclntsh.so

Answer (score 0):

For me it was `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntshcore`. For some reason, the following symlink is missing.

`libclntshcore.so -> /home/ubuntu/ora2pg/instantclient_12_2/libclntshcore.so.12.1`

Answer (score -3):

```
[oracle@em12c bin]$ pwd
/u01/em12c/middleware/oms/bin
[oracle@em12c bin]$ export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/em12c/middleware/oms
[oracle@em12c bin]$ ./genclntsh

[oracle@em12c bin]$ ls -l /u01/em12c/middleware/oms/lib32//libclntsh.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 oracle oinstall 17 Oct 23 22:16 /u01/em12c/middleware/oms/lib32//libclntsh.so -> libclntsh.so.11.1
```

Comment: While this answer is pretty uninformative, it did show me that my issue was that my compiler was not finding `libclntsh.so`.  My problem was that I needed a soft link for my compiler to find the above mentioned file.  Once I did that, it worked ==> `ln -s libclntsh.so.11.1 libclntsh.so`.