# Static linking against external library

Tags: go, linker

I'm trying to understand how to build static executable in Go and I need to link it against external library, in my case ORACLE, but the use case is generic. I do the following:

```
go build -x --ldflags '-s -w -extldflags "-static -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh"'
```

The compilation phase is fine, but linking part fails to find external lib(s):

```
/path/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
/path/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
```

I'm skipping here full path for better readability.
The gcc linker can't see passed -L path and library (in my case -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib -lclntsh).

So, the question is how for any generic case to pass external library path and libs to linker using go build command.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, are you actually using the `$ORACLE_HOME` variable in the command you're executing?

Comment: `-static` instructs the linker not to link dynamic libraries.

Comment: See related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576774/7426

Comment: Adrian, thanks for a tip, I think it is missing point in my question. Since -static flags instructs linker to use static libraries and I don't have such in ORACLE distribution my build fails.